# How to ask friends and customers for business review?

Tags: united-states, friends, work-environment

I just started a new culinary business and it will make me look more credible to have more positive reviews and likes on my business facebook page but I don't get a lot of exposure so it's going slower than I was hoping for.
I nicely asked some of my friends, customers and coworkers who tasted and liked my food to leave a review but some said they would and didn't.

**How do I ask for leaving more feedback on social media without being a nag?**

Comment: Possibly related (other side of the coin) https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/5307/how-to-avoid-writing-yelp-reviews?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Having worked in a small culinary start-up I would recommend not fishing for positive online reviews. It's not necessarily a great look if you end up with a bunch of fake-ish positive reviews.

I'm sure if you check around on Facebook, or the like, you'll notice reviews that come across as a little forced or they look like they were written by employees or friends. Give your future customers some credit, these things often look like what they are.

Good reviews, particularly in the culinary business, tend to be more organic and accumulate slowly over time. Be patient. If your product speaks for itself, the word will travel naturally and the reviews will come along as well.